# Análisis de tiempo de escritura, ofstream versus FILE. C++

Tags: c++, linux, archivo, rendimiento

Quiero hacer unas funciones para escribir logs en un archivo. Cómo espero que se escriba bastantes veces quiero tener el mejor rendimiento, por eso realicé un pequeño programa para comparar ofstream con FILE y fprintf, el código es:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void log_fstream(int n) {
    ofstream f("log.txt", fstream::app);
    f << "hola\n";
    f.close();
}

void log_FILE(int n) {
    FILE *f = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "hola\n");
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        log_fstream(i);
     return 0;
}
```

El problema es que al comparar tiempos, obtengo los siguientes resultados:

Con FILE y fprintf:

```
./log.out  1.27s user 7.61s system 99% cpu 8.930 total
```

Con ofstream:

```
./log.out  1.90s user 3.69s system 98% cpu 5.650 total
```

Parece ser que FILE es más rápido que ofstream, algo que más o menos esperaba, pero el sistema cuando uso FILE se tarda bastante más que cuando uso ofstream, por tanto al final el tiempo total de ofstream es menor.

¿Alguién podría ayudarme a entender tal comportamiento?

Nota: Uso centos 7.

Answer (score 3):

Al trabajar con ficheros de cierto tamaño y con `fstream` (o alguna de sus derivadas) hay que asegurarse de que se establece un tamaño de buffer mayor de cero. Si no se hace así cada vez que se escribe algo en el stream se corre el riesgo de que se produzca un volcado del buffer en el fichero y esta es una operación francamente costosa.

Deberías probar a establecer un tamaño de buffer que evite los volcados frecuentes... claro que a mayor tamaño del buffer mayor será el consumo de memoria... la gracia está en encontrar un equilibrio:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void log_fstream() {
  ofstream f("log.txt", fstream::app);
  f << "hola\n";
  f.close();
}

void log_fstream2() {
  ofstream f("log.txt", fstream::app);
  char buf[100000];
  f.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));
  f << "hola\n";
  f.close();
}

void log_FILE() {
  FILE *f = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  fprintf(f, "hola\n");
  fclose(f);
}

template<typename Func>
void Test(std::string const& title, Func f)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for( int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    f();
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto diff = end - start;
  std::cout << "Test " << std::setw(14) << std::left << (title + ": ") << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " ms\n";
}

int main()
{
  Test("log_FILE",log_FILE);
  Test("log_fstream",log_fstream);
  Test("log_fstream2",log_fstream2);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Test log_FILE:     555.04 ms
Test log_fstream:  881.508 ms
Test log_fstream2: 575.737 ms
```

Ahora ya no hay tanta diferencia entre usar un formato u otro, ¿verdad?

Pero espera que hay más. Hay otro error de concepto en esa prueba y es la creación recurrente del objeto `ofstream`. Vamos a comparar esas dos funciones de test supuestamente iguales:

**log_fstream**

Por cada iteración:

- Crea un objeto de tipo `ofstream`, lo que implica invocar a su constructor por defecto
- Se abre el fichero.
- Se escribe un dato en el fichero.
- Se cierra el fichero.
- Se destruye el objeto `ofstream`, lo que implica invocar a su destructor.

**log_FILE**

Por cada iteración:

- Se abre el fichero.
- Se escribe un dato en el fichero.
- Se cierra el fichero.

Si te fijas, los casos no son realmente iguales... la versión `fstream` realiza dos operaciones adicionales encubierta que son construir el objeto y posteriormente destruirlo.

Si modificamos un poco el código para probar únicamente la operación de escritura nos llevamos otra pequeña sorpresa:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void log_fstream(int n) {
  ofstream f("log.txt", fstream::app);
  for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    f << "hola\n";
  f.close();
}

void log_fstream2(int n) {
  ofstream f("log.txt", fstream::app);
  char buf[100000];
  f.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));

  for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    f << "hola\n";
  f.close();
}

void log_FILE(int n) {
  FILE *f = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    fprintf(f, "hola\n");
  fclose(f);
}

template<typename Func>
void Test(std::string const& title, Func f)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  f(10000);
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto diff = end - start;
  std::cout << "Test " << std::setw(14) << std::left << (title + ": ") << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " ms\n";
}

int main()
{
  Test("log_FILE",log_FILE);
  Test("log_fstream",log_fstream);
  Test("log_fstream2",log_fstream2);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Test log_FILE:     2.96 ms
Test log_fstream:  1.56343 ms
Test log_fstream2: 1.2937 ms
```

Ahora se aprecia claramente como las operaciones de escritura con `fstream` son casi el doble de rápido que las propias con `FILE*`. La penalización la sufres al crear y destruir el objeto... sin embargo en la inmensa mayoría de las veces un fichero se abre para guardar varios cientos o miles de bytes de información, por lo que la penalización de crear y destruir el objeto queda claramente compensada con unos mejores tiempos de escritura.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Pero haciendo pruebas, yo obtengo salidas bastante imprecisas, fstream2 a veces más alto que fstream. Por lo que decidí probar con el comando time de Linux. Y el segundo punto, no crear y destruir cada vez que imprimos, es de gran ayuda. El primer punto del buffer no pude comprobarlo, pero lo tendré en cuenta. El punto es que con esas mejoras y probando con time, obtengo el mismo comportamiento que describí en mi post, FILE es un poco más rápido de fstream, pero el sistema gasta más para este, y al final el tiempo total da muy parecido.

Comment: @manduinca piensa que estás trabajando con sistemas multitarea en vez de con sistema de tiempo real. Ello introduce bastante incertidumbre (tu proceso puede quedar pausado temporalmente porque se está ejecutando un proceso diferente con más prioridad) pero la media va a coincidir con lo que te indico en la respuesta.