# Lectura cin lenta

Tags: c++

Por defecto la lectura con `cin` es desesperadamente lenta en comparación con su homólogo `scanf`... cuando la lógica nos dice que no debería ser así:

- Con `cin` se hace una llamada directa a la función que sabe cual es el tipo de la variable destino.
- Con `scanf` la función debe leer la cadena de formato (con las decenas de posibilidades que existen) para saber cómo debe interpretar la entrada y luego procesarla.

Sin embargo con un sencillo ejemplo es facil ver que la realidad es diferente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

void cinFunc()
{
  int N;
  for( int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    std::cin >> N;
}

void scanfFunc()
{
  int N;
  for( int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    scanf(" %d",&N);
}


template<typename Func>
void Test(std::string const& title, Func f)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  f();
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto diff = end - start;
  std::cout << "Test " << title << ":\t" << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " ms\n";
}

int main()
{
  Test("cin",cinFunc);
  Test("scanf",scanfFunc);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

El programa se ejecuta con un fichero que contiene 200.000 enteros de 1 dígito separados por un espacio y los resultados hablan por si solos:

```
Test cin:       64.7967 ms
Test scanf:     49.855 ms
```

¿Cual es la razón de que la lectura propia de C++ sea tan lenta? ¿Cómo se puede corregir esta situación?

Comment: Relacionada, por si alguien quiere contestarla: [Análisis de tiempo de escritura, ofstream versus FILE. C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/71138/19610).

Comment: @Trauma Realmente no están relacionadas aunque se parezcan... una ataca a ficheros y la otra a la entrada estándar... el verdadero origen de cada problema es distinto..

Comment: Entonces el origen es distinto del que yo creía :-( Dejo el comentario, por si alguien la quiere contestar.

Comment: @Trauma ya está respondida :) Si hubiese visto esa pregunta antes la habría respondido :(

Comment: ¿Dependiente del procesador?

Comment: @NaCl la respuesta publicada va por el buen camino

Comment: No he dicho lo contrario, es simplemente que me parece un poco injusto, realizar pruebas distintas en la misma instancia del programa, debido al mismo problema de la sincronización.

Comment: @NaCl el problema es que la sincronización viene activa por defecto y eso ralentiza en exceso las operaciones de lectura y escritura... aunque por otro lado eso hace que las operaciones sean seguras en entornos multihilo si se intercalan llamadas a la capa C++ y a la capa stdio... si optas por la rapidez mas te vale ser bastante cuidadoso

Comment: Por supuesto parto de la base de que el efecto final dependerá de la implementación para cada compilador, pero es algo que está ahí y que sucede en todas las versiones en mayor o menor medida

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin aquí se observa que desactivando la sincronización iostream es mas rápido

Comment: @cheroky quizás deberías elaborar la correspondiente respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por defecto `iostream` se sincroniza con `stdio` para garantizar que las funciones de entrada y salida estándar tanto de `C` y `C++` compartan un único buffer, ya que sin la sincronización ambos tendrían buffers independientes, esto causaría problemas como:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hola";
    printf("mundo");
    cout << "adios";
}
```

Sin la sincronización nunca sabrás si obtendrás `Holaadiosmundo` o `Holamundoadios` o `adiosholamundo` ya que tanto `printf` y `cout` poseen buffers diferentes en consecuencia el orden es indefinido. Por desgracia el tema de la sincronización introduce una importante penalización de rendimiento para `iostream`, pero es posible desactivarla si no tienes intención mezclar `stdio` y `iostream`.

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Con esto se obtendría un importante aumento en el rendimiento incluso mejor respecto a `stdio`.

Answer (score 3):

he mirado su codigo en [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) y el `cin` es mas rapido que con el uso de `scanf`, al ver eso le quite las optimizaciones y sigue siendo mas rapido el `cin`, "no se" a que se debera teniendo encuenta su pregunta y los tiempos que muestra, puede echar un vistazo en el ide online quizas se me esta pasando algo.

Por otro lado puede emplear [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) si usted no precisa synchronized con el estandar c quizas eso le ayude.

---

he mirado tambien en otros ide online como [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/031c5954eb2abc67) y lo mismo, coliru usa GCC 7.1.0, por si le es de ayuda, el test de coliru tampoco tiene ninguna optimizacion y es sobre `-std=c++11`